# What are the total number of users operating in a linux os at a time?

Tags: linux, operating-system

*I wanted to know the answer since I couldn't find it anywhere.*

Comment: It is unclear what is meant by this question. Do you want to know how many users are currently active? How many user accounts there are? How many there can be? This sounds like homework, read your homework.

Comment: Your question is not well defined. Humans able to use a given OS ? Defined accounts ? Logged-in ?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Yes, I meant how many maximum users can be active at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the maximum [UID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Type) and [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier). UIDs are 32 bit, so it can be 4,294,967,296, but [PID range](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) is narrower: 2^22, which is exactly: **4,194,304**. This is the theoretic maximum; in real world there are some running daemons already, so **approximately 4 million**. (on 32bit it's only 32,768)

Answer (score -2):

You can use "word count" command like below :

```
users | wc -w
```

Answer (score -2):

Theoretically you can have as many users as the user ID space supports. To determine this on a particular system check out the definition of the uid_t type. It is usually defined as unsigned_int or int. On intel architectures, sizes are defined in `/usr/include/bits/typsizes.h`. You can check value of this variable in your system by typing following command on terminal

**`cat /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h | grep UID_T`**

In my system, output of this command shows:

## define __UID_T_TYPE    __U32_TYPE

This means system can host 4294967296 (2^32) different users. However, other resources may become exhausted before you reach this limit, e.g. disk space. If you create a home directory for each user then even with just 1MB of space for each user you need over 4PBs of storage. Also, large number of users leaving processes running in the background, scheduling cron jobs, opening ftp and/or ssh sessions can create a severe burden on the system.

**Limit for simultaneous logins:**

When logging in using SSH, you use a pseudo-terminal (a pty) allocated to the SSH daemon, not a real one (a tty). Pseudo-terminals are created and destroyed as needed. You can find the number of ptys allowed to be allocated at one time by

**`cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max`**

In my system, output of this command shows:

**4096**

This means 4096 users can simultaneously login on this machine (remote login).

*PS: My Linux distribution is 64-bit Fedora 23*

```
PS.PS: Please don't forget to mark answered. And hit my rating. Thank you :)
```

Comment: Possible plagiarism? https://answers.splunk.com/answers/577899/splunk-enterprise-maximum-local-users.html You should, at the very least, cite your source.

Comment: Lot of them.. I don't see reason to write the same all the time.. Original post is always hard to find.. and researching also deserves some points. :) 
Here it is the source :https://www.quora.com/How-many-maximum-users-can-be-created-on-Linux